Why does the particle system disappear when I apply the modifier?
I made a tennisball with a particle system to create some fuzz. I want to use it in another Blender file so I want to apply the ParticleSystem modifier so I can also scale it. However, when I apply the modifier the particle system disappears. Why is that?
Here is the file: 



I'm not sure what the Apply is for, maybe you want to convert the hair to meshes?

I want to apply it so I can scale the object without issue. If I don't apply it and then scale it messes up the particle system

A mesh object without any modifier on it can only contain mesh data. So applying a modifier which manipulates the mesh like subdivision, displacement etc. is no problem because in the end it results in just a different mesh. Hair particles however are basically curves, and if you wanted them to stay on the object after applying the modifier, the mesh object would have to contain curve data as well which is not possible.

You might want to explore geometry nodes to scatter your particles

The comments above already explained to you why applying the particle modifier doesn't actually bake the particles onto the mesh.
If all you want to do is reuse this asset and scaling it around. One easy way to do that is to put the ball into a collection using Ctrl+G

Then you can instantiate a copy of that collection anywhere in the scene and transform it how you like:


